# SObject row does not allow errors in Salesforce before trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I wrote this logic inside a before insert/update trigger to apply a validation logic. But I am getting  error saying - SObject row does not allow errors. Althought the text inside addError is appearing in the debug log but its not showing up in the call object as desired from the code. 
Below is the code. Kindly assist on how to avoid the error.

```
 trigger Call_Sample_Limit_Check on Call2_Sample__c (before insert, before update) {  
 if (Trigger.new != null) {
  Map<Call2_c,Integer> callErrorMap = new Map<Call2__c,Integer>();
  callErrorMap=Call_Sample_Limit.callSample(Trigger.new);
  Set<Call2__c> callErrorSet= callErrorMap.keySet();
    if(callErrorMap.size()>0){
      for(Call2__c c:callErrorSet ){
            if(callErrorMap.get(c)==1){
                c.addError('You ve exceeded your limit for this call');
            }
        }
    }        
  }
}
```

Comment: Your trigger is on `Call2_Sample_vod__c` but you are trying to add the error to a `Call2_vod__c` object. Is that a typo? You will also need to include the logic from `Call_Sample_Limit.callSample` if you want an answer to your problem.

Comment: I had an issue once with a trigger that did a validation and returned an error with 'addError' too. Turned out to be my fault, because Salesforce doesn't allow you to use this method in an object that is already in the database (or at least that was my conclusion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error arises when you try to call `addError` in a trigger but call it on a record that is not in the trigger collection, which is exactly what you are doing. You can only validate records that are being acted on.